# Find last not empty cell in a range (not in a column)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the last non-empty cell in a given range. My solution does not work...

```
Public Sub Table_And_Layout()
    Dim wsRoadmap As Worksheet
    Dim rGoalL As Range

    Set wsRoadmap = Sheets("Roadmap")

    Set rGoalL = wsRoadmap.Range("A12:A20").End(xlUp)
    MsgBox rGoalL.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: **What do you mean last** when the range includes multiple rows and columns and empty cells.? Please be more specific and give an example.

Do you want to find the column with the most data in rows, or the row with the most data in columns or the bottom right filled cell or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the cell most on the right in the rows covered by your range, try this:

```
Public Sub Table_And_Layout()
    Dim wsRoadmap As Worksheet
    Dim rTarget As Range
    Dim rGoalL As Range
    Dim dColumn As Double
    
    Set wsRoadmap = Sheets("Roadmap")
    
    For Each rTarget In wsRoadmap.Range("A12:A20")
        If dColumn < wsRoadmap.Cells(rTarget.Row, wsRoadmap.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Then
            Set rGoalL = wsRoadmap.Cells(rTarget.Row, wsRoadmap.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)
            dColumn = rGoalL.Column
        End If
    Next
    
    
    MsgBox rGoalL.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Data sample please.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the cells of the range, from the lowest row up and checking (`For Each myCell In myRange(i).Cells`) should be ok:

```
Function GetLastNonEmptyRow(myRange As Range) As Long
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim firstCell As Long: firstCell = myRange.Cells(1, 1)        
    Dim myCell As Range
    
    For i = firstCell + myRange.Rows.Count To firstCell Step -1
        For Each myCell In myRange(i).Cells
            If myCell <> "" Then
                GetLastNonEmptyRow = myCell.Row
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next myCell
    Next i
            
    GetLastNonEmptyRow = -1 'means that the whole range is non-empty
            
End Function
```

Called this way:

```
Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = Worksheets(1).Range("F8:G11")
    Debug.Print GetLastNonEmptyRow(myRange)
        
End Sub
```